# Error: The permission type field is required when creating permission using Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to share a file using the Google Drive API. I have the file ID and the email to share the file to, but I keep getting an error "The permission type field is required". I've followed all the instructions on the API guide, but nothing seemed to fix this.

I'm calling the following function, and I can't tell why this isn't working. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong please?

```
function shareFile(id, email) {
    gdapi.permissions.create({
        fileId: id,
        resources: {
            role: "reader",
            type: "anyone",
            emailAddress: email
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to create a permission with `role: "reader"` and `type: "anyone"` using googleapis of Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for files in Google Drive using Drive API.
- `gdapi` in your script can be used for creating the permission to the file in Google Drive.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- `resources` is not used. Please modify `resources` to `resource` or `requestBody`.
- If you want to use `role: "reader"` and `type: "anyone"`, please remove `emailAddress: email`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function shareFile(id, email) {
    gdapi.permissions.create({
        fileId: id,
        resource: {  // Modified
            role: "reader",
            type: "anyone",
            // emailAddress: email  // Modified
        }
    });
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, plese use the latest version of googleapis. In the current stage, the latest version is `googleapis@47.0.0`.
- If you want to give `role: "reader"` to `emailAddress: email`, please modify as follows.

  ```
  function shareFile(id, email) {
      gdapi.permissions.create({
          fileId: id,
          resource: {  // Modified
              role: "reader",
              type: "user",  // Modified
              emailAddress: email
          }
      });
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)
- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem I had was that I put "resources" instead of "resource" and I had put "anyone" instead of "user". This completely fixes my problem. :)

Comment: @Justin Chang Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.